# Origin of 'acle' ending in words

Tags: etymology

What is the origin and meaning of the *acle* ending in words like *oracle, debacle, tabernacle, miracle, spectacle*. Or are there more than one explanation/meaning here?

Comment: Even [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tabernacle) gives brief etymologies. The Latin suffix *-aculum* indicates a diminutive.

Answer (score 3):

Most of them seem to get their **-acle** suffix from the Latin **-culum** suffix, which sounds reasonable.

This is not always true, however, if you look at [coracle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=coracle&searchmode=none) or [barnacle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=barnacle&searchmode=none) for instance.

(You can check the other examples on the same site as well.)

Comment: Another small counterexample: [treacle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=treacle)